# received runtime error 13 will utilizing instring function

Tags: excel, vba

[image]when i import a file the second time, the data from the first time is not being deleted. Thus, once i import the second file, the second file data starts at the column beside the first data. My code below, after the import part is what i tryna resolve this issue

```
Sub ImportCMOSLog(Path As String, filename As String)
    'Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
 
    Sheets("Data").Select
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'ActiveSheet.Name = filename
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = filename
    Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Path & filename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = filename                                                    'change activesheet to sheets("Data")
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "Time/min"
    
    Dim x As String
    Dim sheet As String
    Dim myrange As String
    sheet = "Data"
    myrange = "$A$1:$BC$1"
    Set x = Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$BC$1") [object required error over here]
    
    
    
    For Each Cell In x
        If InStr(x.Value, strSearch) > 0 Then                 [runtime error received over here]
            lastrow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
            Columns("B:B").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time/min"
            Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastrow, 2)).Select
            Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]-R3C1)*24*60"
            Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        Else
            Sheets("Data").Cells.Clear
        End If
    Next Cell
```

Comment: `Dim x As String` should be `Dim x As Range`

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i have edited my question!

Comment: Ok but what are you trying in the for loop becuase i got confused there. Inserting column in col B and putting some formula? What exactly are you trying. Also did the error go away after you did what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: No, i just wanted to prevent the file from being next to each other. I want the last file to be deleted everytime after i imported a new file to the data sheet

Comment: Then why are you searching for the text? Simply clear the sheet before importing the data?

Comment: Please don't repeat post. Fix either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930717/how-to-stop-excel-changing-my-sheetname-while-using-query  or this one and delete the other. Make one clear question that addresses the comments you have received. It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: i have trouble clearing the data

Comment: I have posted an answer. you may have to refresh the page to see it? Let me know if that is what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it complex then required (*I could be wrong about this*) but what you are actually trying to do is

1. Clear old data
2. Insert new data which had headers as `Date`, `Y1` and `Y2`
3. Insert a column in `B`
4. Give it a header `Time/min` so that new headers are `Date`, `Time/min`, `Y1` and `Y2`
5. Insert the formula in column `B`

If my understanding is correct, then try this (**UNTESTED**). Let me know if you get any errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCMOSLog(Path As String, filename As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & Path & filename, Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = filename
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
            .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        
        .Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        .Range("B1").Value = "Time/min"
        
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("B2:B" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]-R3C1)*24*60"
    End With
End Sub
```